# Decrypting cipher with aes-256-cbc with iv using nodejs crypto module

Tags: node.js, encryption

Am porting a python AES-256 Encrypt/Decrypt method to its nodejs equivalent.But am having an error on the nodejs side when decrypting the cipher.

```
crypto.js:267
  this._handle.initiv(cipher, toBuf(key), toBuf(iv));
               ^

Error: Invalid IV length
    at new Decipheriv (crypto.js:267:16)
    at Object.createDecipheriv (crypto.js:627:10)
    at CryptoUtils.AESDecrypt
```

The python Encrypt/Decrypt Method:

```
def AESEncrypt(key, plaintext):
    plaintext = AESPad(plaintext)
    iv = os.urandom(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return iv + cipher.encrypt(plaintext)

def AESDecrypt(key, ciphertext):                        
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size];
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv);
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:]);
    return AESUnpad(plaintext);
```

My nodejs attempt to convert it:

```
AESEncrypt(key, plaintext) {
    const _plaintext = this.AESPad(plaintext)
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(AES_BLOCK_SIZE) //synchronous
    const cipher = crypto
      .createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv)
      .update(_plaintext)
    return iv + cipher
  }

AESDecrypt(key, ciphertext) {
    const iv = ciphertext.slice(0, 16)
    console.log("iv", iv)
    const plaintext = crypto
      .createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv)
      .update(ciphertext.substring(16))
    return this.AESUnpad(plaintext)
```

What am i doing wrong? My nodejs version is `v8.11.2` and Python `2.7.15rc1`

Comment: So what have you done to solve the problem?  The error message is pretty explicit - what did you find when you investigated?

Comment: Make sure the IV has the right size; It should be 16 bytes.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark I have read the Nodejs documentation on crypto module and python source code on the implementation of the AES class,I have tried converting the cipher to hex before slicing but still the iv length is invalid.

Comment: @t.m.adam I think `ciphertext.slice(0, 16)` does that.IV is the first 16 bytes.

Comment: In `AESEncrypt` you forget to use `.final()`. Try: `Buffer.concat([iv, cipher.update(_plaintext), cipher.final()])`